# Ограничение внешнего ключа при обновлении в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Делаю приложение MVC Database First с Entity Framework. Есть две связанные по полю "Код врача" таблицы (первичный ключ в таблице "Врач"). В базе данных у этих таблиц настроено каскадное обновление.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке обновить эти модели лезет Foreign key constraint исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из контроллера ниже

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Идентификатор_врача doc)
{
    {
        using (var newdbModel = new Entities())
        {
            newdbModel.Идентификатор_врача.Attach(doc);

            var edit = newdbModel.Идентификатор_врача.Where(x => x.Идентификатор_врача1 == doc.Идентификатор_врача1).FirstOrDefault();
            doc.Врач.Фамилия_врача = edit.Врач.Фамилия_врача;
            doc.Врач.Имя_врача = edit.Врач.Имя_врача;
            doc.Врач.Отчество_врача = edit.Врач.Отчество_врача;
            doc.Врач.Код_учреждения_здравоохранения = edit.Врач.Код_учреждения_здравоохранения;
            doc.Категория = edit.Категория;
            doc.Код_специальности = edit.Код_специальности;
            doc.Код_врача = edit.Врач.Код_врача;
            newdbModel.Entry(doc).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            newdbModel.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Отвыкайте использовать кириллицу в  именах сущностей. Оставьте эту привилегию разработчикам 1С. Перемешивание двух языков в коде затрудняют его чтение.

Comment: Проблема может быть тут `doc.Код_врача = edit.Врач.Код_врача`

Comment: Сложно читать код и недостаточно информации, но судя по всему doc и doc.Врач приходит с фронта. И ЕФ пытается создать нового врача по  doc.Врач. Проверьте не нулл ли doc.Врач.Код_врача. Ну и в целом весь этот код надо переписывать.